# Cannot embed stylesheets results in error

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

For some reason stylesheets will NOT load no matter what it results in an error everytime but javascript is perfectly fine.

This is my header.php if it helps: (http://pastebin.com/DLYkJ2XZ)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>GameFinder</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
```

I have honestly no idea why it would not load and give an error.

The error;

```
Notice: Undefined property: Application::$method in /Users/admin/Google Drive/Projects/GameFinder/library/classes/Application.php on line 28

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, second array member is not a valid method in /Users/admin/Google Drive/Projects/GameFinder/library/classes/Application.php on line 28
```

I thought it might be because of calling a url but then why would java embedding be perfectly fine?

Comment: The errors noted here are strictly PHP errors, and have nothing to do with stylesheets, except for possibly the side effect of breaking the HTML's rendering with the displayed error message. You will need to post the relevant PHP code rather than the HTML template header. it points to faulty code in Application.php, line 28.

Comment: changed error to code snippet instead of bolded text

Answer (score 0):

Could your stylesheet be failing to load because the href uses a relative url instead of an absolute one?  Do you use FireBug or Chrome developer tools to see what url the browser is trying to load?  If you view the source of your broken page does it look like what you included above?

I would try making your stylesheet link tag like this and see if it helps:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```